# OpenOffice spreadsheet import into HSQLDB

Tags: openoffice.org, hsqldb, file-conversion

OpenOffice ships with HSQLDB.  Is it possible to easily import the contents of an OO spreadsheet into the built in database?  An added nice to have would be to include the formatting of the cell contents.  ie. colors, line feeds, etc.

This question has gone unanswered so I'm offering a bounty.  Please provide the code to the solution.

The provided link does work, and no coding is required.  To summarize:

1. Create and register an Open Office DB.
   1.1 Looks like you can register any DB for which you have a JDBC driver. (ie. MySql,Postgres)
2. Create column headings in row 1.
3. Select data and copy it to the clipboard.
   3.1  Limited selection to only the desired rows because OO crashed when I selected all rows.
4. Go to the Table (Tables pane) view of the database.
5. Right-click and paste your data.
6. Follow the instructions provided my the wizard that opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you would call it easy, but apparently there are ways to import data into open office's base database.

This [article](http://sheepdogguides.com/fdb/fdb1imp1.htm) explains how to manually import data into the database.  And this [article](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid39_gci1222186,00.html) has more pretty pictures for the same process.  One reason you may not be getting the answer that you want, is that there is very little detail in your question. You could add some more and maybe someone out there can help.

Comment: You have columns A,B,C with a dozen rows of data.  How do you import the 12 rows into a table with 3 columns?  The 1st column is a number and the other 2 are strings.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a programming language, or manually?
  If it's a language, which language are you using?

Comment: Hey thanks for accepting the answer, I hope everything worked out.